# Error: Unable to access jarfile

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, heroku

Estou tentando fazer deploy da minha aplicação no heroku a semanas e sempre obtenho erros.
eu tinha um erro de dynos, criei um arquivo Procfile com o seguinte conteúdo: `web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/CadUnico-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`, mas agora nos Logs tenho o seguinte erro: `Error: Unable to access jarfile target/CadUnico-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`.

Não tenho o arquivo .jar na pasta target, pois não sei gerar tal arquivo, preciso de ajuda para resolver este erro e subir a aplicação corretamente.

link do repositório: https://github.com/Rafael472/CadUnico
Estou a disposição a adicionar mais informações caso necessário.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.pio</groupId>
    <artifactId>CadUnico</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>CadUnico</name>
    <description>Cadastro de Pessoas/Usuarios </description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>   
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: é complicado pessoal, estou tentando tirar dúvida e aprender, e ao invés de comentar, dar dica ou algo do tipo, as pessoas simplesmente dão voto negativo na pergunta, a partir disso a pergunta não fica bem ranqueada e provavelmente não é respondida. comunidade tóxica.

Comment: Uma coisa importante... você deve postar seu código por escrito (copiando e colando aqui no stackoverflow) e não uma imagem dele.
No momento de postar qualquer código, certifique que esteja fazendo do jeito correto, conforme as instruções do fórum.

Comment: @leandro.dev ok, irei mudar a pergunta e lembrarei disso nas próximas. obrigado pela dica.

Comment: @leandro.dev muito obrigado, consegui gerar o arquivo jar. vou editar a pergunta colocando meu Pom.xml no modo código, garanto que sua resposta ajudará muita gente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acesse a pasta do projeto de um terminal e rode `mvn package` para gerar o jar.
O jar será gerado dentro da pasta `target`.

Esse comando mvn é do maven.